Mount IKEA wall cabinet
I have an ikea wall cabinet 30x30x15 that I’m mounting to drywall into studs. I’m not using their fancy bracket… But rather using I guess two wood screws in the fashion of the manual below… Question is are these wood screws OK to support the load or should I use something more like lag bolts?



The screws should be fine if you screw them into studs.

It could be that the back of the cabinet and/or the joint with the sides isn't strong enough to support the necessary weight involved here, and the mounting brackets are intended to spread the weight load over the sides as well as the back of the cabinet. Sometimes bad things can happen if you don't follow instructions.

@gnicko I am following the directions - just curious about the screws

OK. But the instructions specifically say not to use wood screws thru. the brackets....

The directions include a bracket on both options so not using one is not following the directions. Flatpack stuff (which IKEA mostly is) have backs that are sometimes no more than high grade cardboard. The directions also direct you NOT to use flathead screws, but to use panhead screws

I think you made a BIG terminology error. I think what you meant to say is you are not using the Ikea suspension rail. If that's so you should edit your question. If you don't plan on using the bracket that you posted pictures of then the answers below are spot on.


I’m not using their fancy bracket…

The bracket looks like it allows you to attach the wooden sides to the stud.  Without them, you are probably attaching cardboard or thin MDF to the stud.
As RMDman already commented, the screws should be fine into the studs.  You need the bracket to connect to the sides, because the backing of those cabinets often isn't strong enough to hold the weight of the cabinet.  I.e. the problem isn't that the screws aren't strong enough, it's that the backing of the cabinet might not be strong enough to support the screws.
Lag bolts won't fix the backing.  There might be an equivalent that would attach more strongly to the backing.  But the backing might not be securely attached to the rest of the cabinet.
You risk having two screws sticking out of the wall while the cabinet falls to the floor.  The screws might tear through the backing or the backing might pop out of the cabinet.  The backing is not meant to be load bearing.  It just keeps the cabinet square and serves an aesthetic purpose.
If you really don't like the brackets, you might take a thin piece of wood (e.g. a 1"x2") or a thicker (1/2") piece of plywood and screw it into the sides of the cabinet so as to create a thicker backing.  Then you can screw through that (and the current backing) into the studs.  The problem with that solution is that the sides of the cabinet are not that thick.  You'd risk splitting them.  Using the brackets as designed would be safer.
You only show parts of two pages from the instructions.  Both pages show a bracket connecting to the sides that allows you to screw through the backing.  One of the pages tells you not to use screws like the ones that you show.  They want you to use screws that have heads that screw down flat against the bracket.  The screws that you show will anchor firmly into the stud.  Under some circumstances (e.g. a sharp upward blow against the cabinet from someone hitting their head against the cabinet), they might allow the bracket to pull loose from the screw.

A lag bolt offers no advantage screwing into drywall without a stud. A lag bolt is not a rywall anchor, and hanging a shelving unit on drywall anchors is a foolish gamble even with the right sort of anchors.

but the directions say you can mount it without their wall mount bracket which is usually used for mounting more than one cabinet.

There are two ways of mounting Ikea's Sektion cabinets:

Clipping them onto the rail they sell for the purpose.
Screwing the side brackets directly to the wall, preferably into a stud.

Both methods depend on the two metal brackets shown in the instructions which are attached to the side pieces by three screws, as the fibreboard back of the cabinet can not bear significant weight.
If you use the second method, without the rail, you need round head screws, not flat head (see top of left page).
Using the rail offers several advantages, even for a single cabinet (just cut it to suitable length):

You should be able to line up holes in the rail with the position of your studs, regardless of where you want to mount the cabinet. You are unlikely to have studs positioned just where you want to mount the cabinet.
It is much easier to position the light piece of rail so it is level when mounting it than it is to hold up the cabinet.


YES! the second option is the one I’m going with - guess I gotta get some pan head screws.

The question is not liking or liking the bracket, but its function.
It has been designed to hold the cabinet.
While using those screws (the wrong type) into a stud, the screw will stay, but it will rip through the back wall.
Back-wall is made of 1/4 inch cardboard type, thus very thin and soft, and the screw head will rip true it.
If you insist using a screws without bracket at least use large (1.5-3 inch) washers to prevent the screw head ripping through the back-wall.

but the directions say you can mount it without their wall mount bracket which is usually used for mounting more than one cabinet.
